# DHCP Server not starting up on boot

Tags: dhcp, services

I have installed isc-dhcp-server on my Raspbian OS RPi. The RPi boots up after my switch and other devices have successfully booted. However the DHCP server does not start automatically while other services like `bind9` and `smbd` would have started automatically. Issueing the `service isc-dhcp-server status` returns the following:

```
isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server; generated; vendor preset:  enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-01-22 15:43:04 -02; 12min ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 408 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 22 15:43:02 lomakupi05 dhcpd[550]: WARNING: Host declarations are global.  They are not limited to the scope you declared them in.
Jan 22 15:43:02 lomakupi05 dhcpd[550]: Wrote 0 deleted host decls to leases file.
Jan 22 15:43:02 lomakupi05 dhcpd[550]: Wrote 0 new dynamic host decls to leases file.
Jan 22 15:43:02 lomakupi05 dhcpd[550]: Wrote 5 leases to leases file.
Jan 22 15:43:04 lomakupi05 isc-dhcp-server[408]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
Jan 22 15:43:04 lomakupi05 isc-dhcp-server[408]:  failed!
Jan 22 15:43:04 lomakupi05 systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 22 15:43:04 lomakupi05 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
Jan 22 15:43:04 lomakupi05 systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 22 15:43:04 lomakupi05 systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Do a search for isc-dhcp-server not starting at boot -- I got this link.  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=66387

Comment: Seems your `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` is misconfigured. Check with `~$ sudo dhcpd -t`. Look at `~$ man dhcpd.conf`. Maybe `~$ journalctl --catalog --unit=dhcpd` give you some more information.

Comment: I'm able to restart the server manually. I ll recheck the config file

Comment: I found this solution in another topic here and worked for me. In case anyone needs: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70517/isc-dhcp-server-needs-to-be-restarted-after-reboot/70536#70536?newreg=3bdfb28a3a444ab280efc9d0d34ca25d